# How to prevent a web application host from stealing your code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting

Let's say I upload my Rails application to a host (heroku). The application is successful with lots of users and the value of the DB increases as more users enter information. What would prevent heroku copying the app code and/or the DB?

Comment: Heroku would lose most of their business if they were caught doing that. It is in their best interest to be ethical. I know their business would go down significantly if they stole apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they're pretty clear about it here:

http://policy.heroku.com/promise

> Heroku's promises to our customers:
>
> - You own your code, not us
> - You own your data, not us

I would also assume Amazon would have something to say about it if a company built and running on their platform was involved in any unethical business practices.  And they have more lawyers than you, me or Heroku.

Also, keep in mind that other "data stores" that tie into Heroku, such as [Cloudant](http://addons.heroku.com/cloudant) or [MongoHQ](http://addons.heroku.com/mongohq) might have their own data usage policies (though I'm sure Heroku reviews them thoroughly before partnering with them), which you'd be well advised to acquaint yourself with before storing potentially valuable data on them.

Answer (score 4):

It would be a violation of their terms of service, and you could sue them.  On the other hand, they probably have more and better lawyers than you do.

In the case of a reputable host such as Heroku, you are protected by the fact that their primary revenue source is hosting, and they won't want to give up that business by violating the trust of their users.  For less reputable hosts, well, that is the chance you take.  You are also protected, of course, by the fact that the most likely outcome is that your application will not, in fact, collect enough user data to be valuable.  No offense -- just playing the odds.

Comment: Seriously, if the app were that valuable, why would a hosting plan be necessary.